# Regex pattern in PHP that extract English word from its past form to present and vice-versa...?

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a PHP regex pattern that could extract English word from its past form to present, continuous form to present and vice-versa.

Example: wanted -> want, played -> play, cooked -> cook

cook -> cooked, play -> played....

Also: caring -> care, playing -> play, cooking -> cook

care -> caring, play -> playing and so on....

Comment: English is an __irregular__ language, so you can't use __regular__ expressions to do this.... though a [Brill Parser](http://phpir.com/part-of-speech-tagging/) might be a good starting point, allowing you to find the type and root of words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can identify your word as verb, your first demand is pretty easy:

```
$present_tense = preg_preplace('/(ed)$/', '', $word);
```

But even the the first two examples of the continous form show irregular behaviour: with caring, there is added an e to gain care, with play, there is only the -ing removed.

If you have word lists, you could generate pattern -> replacement arrays, which you can use in a single [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) call:

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/\\bcare\\b/i';    // these can be automatically
$patterns[1] = '/\\bplay\\b/i';    // generated if you have only the
$patterns[2] = '/\\bcook\\b/i';    // words in an array
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'caring';
$replacements[1] = 'playing';
$replacements[0] = 'cooking';
$present_tense = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $sentence);
```

This also works with sentences, because the words to change are known and can be picked out by the regex. [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will not be suitable here, because it cannot identify word boundaries.

That is what you can do with regexes. For a more complete solution, you will have to search for libraries with more sophistication, like the one mentioned in the comment above.